# How can i set the sending port in SCTP client?

Tags: client, sctp

How can i set the sending port in SCTP client? . I saw some programmes on internet, but all examples uses system port while sending through SCTP client. The sending port is not defined in SCTP client programme itself.

I want to make SCTP client which uses its own port defined in programme itself.

Best Regards,
Himanshu

Answer (score 0):

```
  strncpy(buffer, "Hello Server", 12);
  buffer[12]='\0';

  connSock = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_SCTP );

  if(connSock == -1)
    die("socket()");

  bzero( (void *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr) );
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(MY_PORT_NUM);
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "127.0.0.1" );

  ret = connect( connSock, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr) );

  if(ret == -1)
     die("connect()");

    ret = sctp_sendmsg( connSock, (void *)buffer, (size_t)strlen(buffer),
                       NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
```